# Having issues when 2 users are working with the same program

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class DataAccess
    Dim dataAcc As New DataAccess
    Public Shared dtx As New DataTable
    Private Shared ConStr As String = "Server = 10.18.206.30;database=PeajeFacturacion;User ID=FacturacionUsr;Password = ukShLq?U6&hNxDxN+67!XaYq"
    Public Shared Function AddOneRecord(PK As String) As DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                    cmd As New SqlCommand("Select c.idCruce, c.FechaCruce, c.HoraCruce, c.claseVehiculo, c.Importe,

 c.codigoCobro, n.nomCaseta 
from dbo.Cruce AS c
JOIN dbo.nombre_caseta AS n 
ON n.numCaseta=c.ClavePlaza 
where c.CodigoCobro = @PK;", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PK", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PK
                cn.Open()
                dtx.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
            Return dtx
        End Function
    End Class
```

I use that part to create the connection just like the example @Mary posted. Then:

```
Protected Sub btnAgregar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAgregar.ServerClick
    Dim numTicket As String = txtNoTicket.Text

    Dim dtx As New DataTable
    Dim pk As String
    pk = txtNoTicket.Text

    Dim con2 As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Dim dtx2 As DataTable
    Dim status As Boolean = False

    'If Not Integer.TryParse(ticket.Text, pk) Then
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pk) Then
        'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "showDisplay();", True)
        cFunciones.mostrarDivAlertaAA("Type a number", "dangerNormal", Me.Page, "")
    Else


        dtx = DataAccess.AddOneRecord(pk)
```

So when adding tickets the issue is the ticket 1 user adds, gets added to the other user even though they use different sessions and different computers. The program is in test fase right now.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the ticket gets added to the other user?  Are you saying it gets saved with the incorrect user details?  It looks to me you running a query based on the primary key (guessing that's what the pk variable is) .  That will just return the records that match no matter which user adds it.  Maybe you need to add a user identifier into your query?

Comment: Hello Hursey. The program is being tested right now by 2 users, each of them with their own username and password so the issue is that when 1 of the users looks for a ticket in the db and that ticket gets added to the gridview, if the other user added a different ticket a few seconds before; the second user gets the ticket of the first user as well so the information is merging for some reason even though each have their own username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of Shared in the `DatAccess` class.  Then each instance of the class will have its own data. Now you must declare an instance of the class and call the method on that instance.

```
Public Class DataAccess
    Dim dataAcc As New DataAccess
    Public dtx As New DataTable
    Private ConStr As String = "Server = 10.18.206.30;database=PeajeFacturacion;User ID=FacturacionUsr;Password = ukShLq?U6&hNxDxN+67!XaYq"
    Public Function AddOneRecord(PK As String) As DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("Select c.idCruce, c.FechaCruce, c.HoraCruce, c.claseVehiculo, c.Importe,
                                        c.codigoCobro, n.nomCaseta 
                                        from dbo.Cruce AS c
                                        JOIN dbo.nombre_caseta AS n 
                                        ON n.numCaseta=c.ClavePlaza 
                                        where c.CodigoCobro = @PK;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PK", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PK
            cn.Open()
            dtx.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Return dtx
    End Function
End Class

Protected Sub btnAgregar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAgregar.ServerClick
    Dim dtx As New DataTable
    Dim pk = txtNoTicket.Text
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pk) Then
        cFunciones.mostrarDivAlertaAA("Type a number", "dangerNormal", Me.Page, "")
    Else
        Dim datAcc As New DataAccess
        dtx = datAcc.AddOneRecord(pk)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Mary, thank you for the example I was missing the Dim datAcc As New DataAccess part, the issue was solved by one my coworkers but he did something different, I don´t understand exactly what because I didn´t get so see the code but he created a procedure to clean the DataAccess each time it gets used or something like that... But anyway, I think your solution is much better so I´m going to propose to use this one instead. I really appretiate your help, you have helped me a lot, thank you.